# Algorithm for minimum vertex cover in Bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, matching, bipartite, vertex-cover

I am trying to figure out an algorithm for finding minimum vertex cover of a bipartite graph.

I was thinking about a solution, that reduces the problem to maximum matching in bipartite graph. It's known that it can be found using max flow in networ created from the bip. graph.

Max matching M should determine min. vertex cover C, but I can't cope with choosing the vertices to set C. 
Let's say bip. graph has parts X, Y and vertices that are endpoints of max matching edges are in set A, those who are not belong to B.

I would say I should choose one vertex for an edge in M to C. 
Specifically the endpoint of edge e in M that is connected to vertex in set B, else if it is connected only to vertices in A it does not matter. 
This idea unfortunately doesn't work generally as there can be counterexamples found to my algorithm, since vertices in A can be also connected by other edges than those who are included in M.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kőnig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)

Answer (score 2):

[Kőnig's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_theorem_(graph_theory)) proof does exactly that - building a minimum vertex cover from a maximum matching in a bipartite graph.

Let's say you have `G = (V, E)` a bipartite graph, separated between `X` and `Y`.

As you said, first you have to find a maximum matching (which can be achieved with [Dinic's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) for instance). Let's call `M` this maximum matching.

Then to construct your minimum vertex cover:

- Find `U` the set (possibly empty) of unmatched vertices in `X`<sup>1</sup>, ie. not connected to any edge in `M`
- Build `Z` the set or vertices either in `U`, or connected to `U` by alternating paths (paths that alternate between edges of `M` and edges not in `M`)
- Then `K = (X \ Z) U (Y ∩ Z)` is your minimum vertex cover

The Wikipedia article has details about how you can prove `K` is indeed a minimum vertex cover.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or Y, both are symmetrical